# How to launch iOS carplay simulator on xcode 6

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6.1, carplay

I need to check how exactly the iOS Carplay works and how to launch it on simulator.
Can someone throw some light on how to start working with Carplay and how to launch it using Xcode 6.1 iOS simulators.

Comment: It is not supported.  Please explain why you "need to check how ... [it] works"

Comment: Then why did they provide car play option in the iOS simulator

Comment: There isn't a CarPlay option in the iOS Simulator.

Comment: It is there under Hardware> externaldisplay >carplay

Comment: It is only present in the menu if you make unsupported changes.  It is not visible by default.

Comment: Okay :) Fine then lets wait till apple officially announces the option.

Comment: @ravoorinandan : do you have any hint how to manage to get this setting visible ? thx.

Comment: @yonel Just create a empty folder by name /AppleInternal in the root folder or in the applications folder to see this option.

Comment: @ravoorinandan :  hum thanks ! with your hint I manage to get the "CarPlay..." menu item, but unfortunately, when I click on it, it doesn't show anything, grrrr ! (I'm running XCode 6.1 with iOS 8.1 simulator)

Comment: @yonel That was the reason i posted this question and didn't get any answer yet :(

Comment: @ravoorinandan Any luck with understanding Car Play? Can we show our own app on Car Play display.

Comment: No Irfan, Unfortunately apple has still blocked or not exposed any api's/ classes for making use of car play:(

Comment: Reading through blogs and forums, Some says that by requesting apple one can grant permission to display app on car play? Any idea

Answer (score 5):

Type in this command in a Terminal window:

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlay -bool YES
```

Then shutdown and restart the Simulator.  There should now be a Hardware->External Display->CarPlay option available.